# Get Order Details

Tags: order-details

I am following [this](http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/magento-get-items-in-order/) article. Now I need more information of Order. I would like to fetch **Ordered Currency, Order Date, Payment Method and Order Status**.
Can anyone say how can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$orderNumber = 100004544;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);
$currency = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
$date = $order->getCreatedAt();
$paymentMethod = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
$status = $order->getStatus();
```